# Вычисление квадратного корня n число раз

Tags: c#, .net

Разбираясь с циклами возник вопрос вычисление корня n число раз. Выглядеть это должно так:

[image: цикл]

Требуется реализовать именно циклом, без рекурсии.

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Необходимо без рекурсии, возможно ли это ?

Comment: Конечно возможно. Любой рекурсивный алгоритм можно переписать на итеративный, использовав стек. А в вашем случае вероятно можно просто циклом обойтись.

Comment: `a1 = myFunc(0) a2 = myFunc(a1) a3 = myFunc(a2) a4 = myFunc(a3) // Где myFunc(x) = КореньИз(2 + x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итеративно, без стека -- просто один цикл:

```
public double Sqrtn(double num, int count)
{
    double result = Math.Sqrt(num);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        result += num;
        result = Math.Sqrt(result);
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Вычисление начинаем "изнутри" формулы и проводим нужное число раундов, выходя "наружу".

Первые несколько итераций для двойки

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    Sqrtn(2, i).Dump();
}
```

дадут такие ответы:

```
1,8477590650225735
1,9615705608064609
1,9903694533443939
1,9975909124103448
1,9993976373924085
1,999849403678289
1,9999623505652022
1,9999905876191524
1,9999976469034038
```

На 27мой итерации выдаёт ответ 2 - это отражение того математического факта, что ваша формула стремится к тому числу, которое стоит под корнем.

Рекурсивная версия:

```
public double Sqrtn(double num, int count)
{
    double result = num;
    
    if(count <= 1)
        return Math.Sqrt(result);
        
    return Math.Sqrt(result + Sqrtn(result, count - 1));
}
```

Первые ответы те же:

```
1,4142135623730951
1,8477590650225735
1,9615705608064609
1,9903694533443939
1,9975909124103448
1,9993976373924085
1,999849403678289
1,9999623505652022
1,9999905876191524
```